# Want non www to resolve to www version of site, but recently changed to ssl and getting confused with the code to add to .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

Hi I recently added my site www.deckitout.co.za and the version deckitout.co.za as properties in google search console. Then I got google to fetch these sites and all there pages as well as the mobile version.PS: My site is using ssl.

I ran an audit on my site and it gave me the following; 
http://www.deckitout.co.za and http://deckitout.co.za/ should resolve to the same URL, but currently do not.

did some reading up and it appeared that I could add some code into the .htaccess file for a permanent redirect from deckitout.co.za to www.deckitout.co.za. The instructions stated using this code;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

is this correct? should it not be the non www first then the www version on the second line?

currently in my .htaccess file I have the following code;

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https ://% {HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

getting a bit confused as my site is https and not http, so what does the eventual code need to look like?

lastly do I need to include any canonical tags etc if I am using a redirect as in above case?

Any assistance hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try you domain with following form of code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Hi Martin,That last line RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC] what do I fill in? do i need to change the http to https and then what format of my URL do I add in there? assuming I want my site to resolve to www.deckitout.co.za (is the .net extension still used, even though my site is .co.za? please clarify! Thanks

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^deckitout.co.za [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.deckitout.co.za [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.deckitout.co.za/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: entered that code thank you, but it appears to still give me the same fail message in the site audit regarding the canonicalisation...http://www.deckitout.co.za and http://deckitout.co.za/ should resolve to the same URL, but currently do not. Also it seems that the ssl is no longer coming up on the site...I just get the "i", in the browser...